# mpi4py: Spawn processes as Python threads for easier debugging

Tags: python, multithreading, mpi, mpi4py

To use mpi4py, the standard approach is to use `mpiexec` to start a program using multiple MPI processes. For example `mpiexec -n 4 python3.5 myprog.py`.

Now, that makes debugging difficult, because one can not straight-forwardly use the Python interpreter plus maybe an IDE debugger using the Python interpreter. However, it is no problem to debug a multi-threaded application.

So my idea would be: **Instead of using mpiexec to spwan the processes, I have a Python script that will spwan several threads, each of them will act as an MPI process, all happening within the Python interpreter.** So the use of `mpiexec` woud not be necessary and I could debug my application like any other multi-threaded Python program. Would that be possible, and how?

(In general, I'd be very happy to find some good example collections or tutorials for mpi4py, there's not very much available.)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to implement any hardcore idea. `mpiexec` is already spawning process for you. Assuming your using the pudb Python debugger you could do the following:

`mpiexec -np 4 xterm -e python2.7 -m pudb.run helloword.py`

The `-e` option of `xterm` is specifying which program `xterm` is going to execute.

PS: I have not test it with Python 3.5 but a similar solution will work

Comment: That's exactly what I try to avoid. I'd like to use it WITHOUT mpiexec, just plain python and then start the threads inside python. That's not very hardcore. If I forgot to mention: That's for ealry testing and prototyping only, of course. 

However, I'm perfectly open to work with mpiexec, as long as it integrates well with the debugger of my IDE (currently PyCharm).

Comment: @Michael, what you are trying to achieve is hardly possible. Virtually all production MPI libraries implement ranks as processes, not as threads. You will have to write an entire stub library that implements the `mpi4py` API using shared memory while emulating process groups with threads. Debugging MPI is far from trivial and there are special parallel debuggers that make use of the client-server approach with debugging agents within each MPI process and a central GUI client.

Comment: Ok, I can not know how you want to use it. MPI defines a Message Passing Interface for Process communication, what will happen if you simulate processes using threads? When you are sending message to "Rank 0" which is inside a thread and the thread is inside a process with other threads, who is going receive it?

Comment: Another thing: because of the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock), I'm not sure using pure Python threads would work all that well. The GIL guarantees that only one Python thread is executing at a time. If what you're trying to debug is some kind of concurrency issue, you might not get an accurate representation of how your program behaves when multiple processes can work.

Comment: Ok, I think the answers are clear: It's not really possible.